# If a series converges, does it fulfill convergence tests?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I was wondering about whether or not convergence tests are iff.

For example, if the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$
converges, does it imply that at least one (other than limit of summand) of the convergence tests is fulfilled? i.e. can one say that the convergence implies, say,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|<1 $$

My gut feeling is that this isn't true, but I can't think of a way to prove it.

Comment: I would advise you to exclude comparison test since for every series with eventually positive terms you can say (crazy enough) that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ converges since $\sum_{n=N}^\infty 2 a_n$ converges. And therefore comparison test is fulfilled.

Comment: That is an exaggerated example btw. But I hope you see my point.

Comment: @Shashi good point. Thanks

Comment: @ItamarG3, if I were not having misunderstanding, so you want to find some example that $a_{n+1}/a_{n}\rightarrow 1$ and the series is still convergent?

Answer (score 0):

Try $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n(\log n)^{2}}$.

Comment: @gimusi that one diverges.

Comment: Ops my faults, Thanks!

Comment: Why my example is recommended to be deleted? Isn't that $a_{n+1}/a_{n}\rightarrow 1$ in this case and the series is convergent so it fulfils the need of OP?